# css border gradient on corners

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to frame my web page, and I want `div`s with just the corners defined. Essentially, I want the top-right and bottom-left corner to have gradient borders. I hope my "ASCII art" makes sense to you.

```
     -    -  -  - - - - ----.
                            |
                            |
                            '
                            |
                            '

                            '

                            '
```

I want the corresponding effect for the bottom-left corner as well.

My incorrect code thus far does not give the desired effect:

```
-webkit-border-image: 
-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(#666), to(#fff)) 1 100%;
```

Comment: [Happy reading!](http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/)

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide and image (or a link to an image) as to what you want it to look like?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you'd like a gradient from top right to bottom left, only showing on the border. As far as I know, you'd either need to create a background image for the whole thing, or at least for the border. Also, only two of five major browsers support gradients like that. Sorry I couldn't offer more help.